# How to avoid incrementals calls to a js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing an app with php and js.
I have a menu sidebar with some items, when I click on a item, with the jQuery load function, the corresponding php file is loaded on the main container.
But I have a very important issue when I load one specific php file.

The idea is that the page does not reload, so that I use jQuery load function.
The problem is this: I charge a view that calls several js functions at a certain point, then I go to another part of the application and when I return to that view in particular, the call to this function is done once over more and if I go out again and again that view, the call is made 3 times and so on.

It make the app very low in a certain time, because the function that is call in a incremental way is a js function that have a ajax call.

This is a part of the js file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        ObtenerNumPaciente();               
        actualizarMedicos();
        actualizarMutuales();           
        resetFormMedico();
        resetPracticas();       
        actualizarNomencladores();      
        $('#nombre').focus();           
    }); 

    $(document).keydown(function(key){
        if (key.which === 113)
        {
            key.preventDefault();               
            actualizarPacientes('key down'); //this is the function that is call several times
            $('#modal-pacientes').modal('show');
        }           
    });

function actualizarPacientes(origin){
        alert('this came from: ' + origin);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'api/pacientes',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", $.cookie('ApiKey'));
            },
            ...
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: A part of your js code would help in solving this issue. This sounds like a small error in the code, but without the code itself it will be tricky to solve.

Comment: Now is updated with some of the code

Comment: Try to add `.unbind('keydown')` before the keydown itself. 
`$(document).unbind('keydown').keydown(function(key){` let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: @Mihailo its works! what does it does the unbind function?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `unbind()` before the keydown itself.

`$(document).unbind('keydown').keydown(function(key){`

Basically you're attaching the event `keydown` **twice** to the document element. [Unbind](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) just "detaches" the event listener, making sure the code within the function triggers once.

So if the element has an **event listener** for *keydown* it will unbind the old one and attach the new one.